# Dynamically update String using JSON object values in JS

Tags: javascript, json, npm, ecmascript-6, string-literals

I have this function to create where it make a request, stores the Data. (Stored as OBJ)

Makes a second request to get a new URL to call. This URL requires me to update the url to include values from the stored data.

The data being saves:

```
{
  "location": {
    "ip": "78.152.221.20",
    "success": true,
    "type": "IPv4",
    "continent": "Europe",
    "continent_code": "EU",
    "country": "Ireland",
    "country_code": "IE",
    "country_flag": "https://cdn.ipwhois.io/flags/ie.svg",
    "country_capital": "Dublin",
    "country_phone": "+353",
    "country_neighbours": "GB",
    "region": "County Dublin",
    "city": "Swords",
    "latitude": "53.4557467",
    "longitude": "-6.2197406",
    "asn": "AS15502",
    "org": "Vodafone Ireland",
    "isp": "Vodafone Ireland Limited",
    "timezone": "Europe/Dublin",
    "timezone_name": "Greenwich Mean Time",
    "timezone_dstOffset": "0",
    "timezone_gmtOffset": "0",
    "timezone_gmt": "GMT 0:00",
    "currency": "Euro",
    "currency_code": "EUR",
    "currency_symbol": "€",
    "currency_rates": "0.926884",
    "currency_plural": "euros",
    "completed_requests": 49
  }
}
```

The second request returns this URL which i need to update:

```
"url": "https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json?lat={{ location.latitude }}&lng={{ location.longitude }}"
```

I have tried to create a function that manipulates the string and return. Once returnd it would be set a a string tempate literal like this:

```
`https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json?lat=${OBJ['location']['latitude']&lng=${OBJ['location']['longitude']`
```

But it is not working, it is just using the string and not taking the values stored previously as OBJ.

Here is my code, any suggestions or pointers or any thing at all would be appreciated.

```
const interpolateURLorMessage = (string) => {
  if (CONST.DEBUG) {
    console.log('functions.checkURLorMessage: string:', string);
  }

  if (!string) {
    return null;
  }

  if (string.includes('{{') && string.includes('}}')) {
    const myRegexp = /\{{(.*?)\}}/g;
    const matches = string.match(myRegexp);

    let newURL = `${string}`;
    matches.forEach((ele) => {
      const match = ele;
      let newMatch = ele.replace('.', '\'][\'');
      newMatch = newMatch.replace('{{', '${OBJ[\'');
      newMatch = newMatch.replace('}}', '\']');
      newMatch = newMatch.replace(/\s/g, '');
      newURL = newURL.replace(match, newMatch);
    });

    return newURL;
  } else {
    // Noting to interpolate
    return string;
  }
};
```

Comment: You don't want to use something like handlebars? That would do the work for you...

Comment: You could do `const parsedURL = Handlebars.compile(url)(locationObj);`

Comment: Note that template literals are essentially Javascript, syntactic sugar over concatenation of strings with expressions, and so you won't be able to modify them at runtime.  That would be self-modifying code or like executing an eval.

Answer (score 0):

Naive implementation that uses a replacer function on the regex and uses split(.) assuming that values in brackets are property values.  If it needs to be more complex you can probably use something similar to eval or more complex parsing.  I believe lodash has some property path accessing functions so you don't have to reinvent it.
Mustache templates might also be an option, and you can precompile them to avoid the overhead.

But this will work for the simple use case you have there.

```js
var OBJ={};CONST={DEBUG:true};

const interpolateURLorMessage = (string) => {
  if (CONST.DEBUG) {
    console.log('functions.checkURLorMessage: string:', string);
  }

  if (!string) {
    return null;
  }

  if (string.includes('{{') && string.includes('}}')) {
    return string.replace(/\{{(.*?)\}}/g,(r,p1)=>p1.trim().split('.').reduce((acc,p)=>acc[p],OBJ));
  } else {
    // Noting to interpolate
    return string;
  }
};

var urlobj = {"url": "https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json?lat={{ location.latitude }}&lng={{ location.longitude }}"};

var data = {
  "location": {
    "ip": "78.152.221.20",
    "success": true,
    "type": "IPv4",
    "continent": "Europe",
    "continent_code": "EU",
    "country": "Ireland",
    "country_code": "IE",
    "country_flag": "https://cdn.ipwhois.io/flags/ie.svg",
    "country_capital": "Dublin",
    "country_phone": "+353",
    "country_neighbours": "GB",
    "region": "County Dublin",
    "city": "Swords",
    "latitude": "53.4557467",
    "longitude": "-6.2197406",
    "asn": "AS15502",
    "org": "Vodafone Ireland",
    "isp": "Vodafone Ireland Limited",
    "timezone": "Europe/Dublin",
    "timezone_name": "Greenwich Mean Time",
    "timezone_dstOffset": "0",
    "timezone_gmtOffset": "0",
    "timezone_gmt": "GMT 0:00",
    "currency": "Euro",
    "currency_code": "EUR",
    "currency_symbol": "€",
    "currency_rates": "0.926884",
    "currency_plural": "euros",
    "completed_requests": 49
  }
};

OBJ=data;
console.log(
interpolateURLorMessage(urlobj.url)
);
```